# Can Xorg-Server and Wayland-Compositor be run simultaneously in Linux?

Tags: linux, xorg, wayland

At graphical login with lightdm I can set which session type to start and am offered:

- Gnome
- Gnome on Xorg
- Xfce session

The first `Gnome` is the Gnome DE running with the standard Wayland backend, and as I understand it means Gnome acts as a wayland protocol compositor, i.e talk to the kernel for KMS and evdev (as displayed on [Wayland Architecture | freedesktop.org](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/architecture.html)), the second option `Gnome on Xorg` when chosen creates also a Gnome session, yet there is a process `Xorg`, i.e. as I can tell an Xorg server running.

I was courious, since both Xorg-Server, as the wayland protocol's compositor might be using similar/same resources (i.e. the graphic adapter) if it is possible to run both at the same time.

I have tested therefore to login, once into a Gnome wayland session and then secondly with another account account in to a Gnome on Xorg session.
The result has been that this seemingly works, yet there are processes named `/usr/bin/Xwayland` running, and I am unsure if the displayed Xorg session, is eventually only "fake", hence displaying via the XWayland "Xorg" server.

Being confused I wanted to pose the question here, whether "Xorg-Server and Wayland-Compositor [can] be run simultanously in Linux?"

Answer (score 5):

They run simultaneously, but they don't control the display simultaneously. Typically, the login screen ends up on the first VT, and your desktop on the second; you can try switching back and forth with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>. You'll find hand-off messages in the logs; for example, in `~/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.1.log`, I see

```
AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
systemd-logind: got pause for ...
```

when switching away from the VT running that X server, and

```
systemd-logind: got resume for ...
AIGLX: Resuming AIGLX clients after VT switch
```

when switching to the VT.

Comment: I tried searching the logs for hand-off messages, which I assumed to be issued by logind and recorded via journald, given I have to life with systemd now. I did nonetheless not see/find any of those hand-off messages in the logs, would you mind to give some info.

Comment: I've added some examples from my X logs.