# Is there a way to know if more than one compositor is running in a session?

Tags: linux, debian, xorg

I got the following info. via inxi -

```
$ sudo inxi -SICGxxx | grep compositor
           Display: server: X.Org 1.20.3 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa compositor: marco v: 1.20.2
```

while I read Stephen's answer in [Can Xorg-Server and Wayland-Compositor be run simultanously in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/345267/can-xorg-server-and-wayland-compositor-be-run-simultanously-in-linux)

I am not sure if only marco is running or others as well, for instance compton -

```
$ aptitude why compton
i   mate-tweak Recommends compton
```

Edit :- I was trying to find/use update-alternatives to tell/see if more than one but didn't know what to use as list ?

Comment: It's challenging, I have not been able to detect even one compositor, nor can I detect if something that can be or not be a composiitor (kwin_x11, for example), is a compositor. I'd love to hear if anyone can solve this problem. My hack solution is just to search ps aux but that actually doesn't tell you if something is compositing, just that something is running. Some, like compton, if they are running are by definition compositing, but that's as close as I've gotten.

Comment: Compton complains if there is another compositor running. is it definitely possible to run more than one compositor? I haven't been able to find the relevant sections in the X documentation

Comment: It seems like you can run at most [one compositor per screen](https://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html#idm140200472516176)