# Wayland vs Xorg vs X11

Tags: x11, xorg, wayland

I am not sure about this but these are my current thoughts. X.org is an implementation of the X11 protocol and X11 is just a **protocol** and not a piece of **software**. My question is that is Wayland a completely new protocol that aims to completely replace X11 or is it supposed to replace X.org and implement X11?
I am relatively new to display managers and WMs so I may need to clear some misconceptions!

Comment: [It's a protocol replacing X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_(display_server_protocol)).

Comment: Note that Wayland is a new protocol for that aims to solve a *different problem* than the X protocol. See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/596894/how-does-linuxs-display-work).

Comment: Yes! Thanks everyone this is all helpful!